# React Router v6: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**When trying to pass a value to the next screen in react-router, I get the following error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

**My Code:**

App.js

```
const App = () => {

const navigate = useNavigation()

const nav = () => {
navigate('next-screen' {username:username})
}

return(
<button onClick = {nav}></button>
)

}
```

nextscreen.js:

```
const NextScreen = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation()
    let username = props.location.username
    return(
        <h1 style={{color:"#FFFFFF"}}>{username}</h1>
    )
    
}
```

username:

```
let [username, setUsername] = React.useState('')
```

Comment: my guess is props.location is not an object. log out `props` and edit your question with the response

Comment: If you use `useLocation` hook, you can access properties from `location` object instead of `props.location`. So try as `location.username`.

Comment: @norbitrial  When trying your method, the username is 'undefined', but it shows no error

Comment: @JohnSneijder Could you please share the **URL** how you are testing your code? Is the `username` should come from a query string?

Comment: @norbitrial  my variable is let [username, setUsername] = React.useState('') as you can see from above.

Comment: @norbitrial no it does not